# Using UnitOfWork design at different endpoints. Can't tracking entity updates when I try to apply savechanges. #.net (UnitOfWork design)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, unit-of-work, savechanges

If I use the two service's method at same action like below It is working.

```
 [HttpPost, Route("save_changes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        _logService.CreateLog(logCreateModel);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

But I need to call the entity updating and SaveChanges methods at different action Because I want to send request from different API.Like this;

```
[HttpPost, Route("create")]
    public async Task CreateLog(LogCreateModel logCreateModel)
    {
        await _logService.CreateLog(logCreateModel);
    }

 [HttpPost, Route("save_changes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

**and this my UnitOfWork class;**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly PrimeLogDatabaseContext _context;
       
    private IRepository<Log> _log;
    private IRepository<LifeCycle> _lifeCycle;

    public UnitOfWork(PrimeLogDatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
  
    public IRepository<Log> log => _log ?? new LogRepository(_context);
    public IRepository<LifeCycle> lifeCycle => _lifeCycle ?? new LifeCycleRepository(_context);

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

How I can?

P.s:
I want to create more than one log and at the end of the request I want commit all logs to database.
I used the UnitOfWork design because I have to seperate SaveChanges method from creation process.
At Another API I have action which including CreateLog request services. And I send request to SaveChanges with using the attribute that trigger when action result.

Comment: Your example makes no sense. Typically with a UnitOfWork pattern, the start and commit of the transaction is separate from any body of work. So you should be explicitly starting and saving your work, regardless of anything else. If you're combining specific functionality with the unit of work abstraction, it is probably incorrect.

Comment: The question makes no sense for another reason. A DbContext is already a unit of work, and since you use `SaveChanges` it sounds like you're actually using DbContext to implement UoW. Since it's scoped to an HTTP Request by default, the unit of work is the request. Not even multiple requests on the same controller, much less different controllers or entirely different endpoints.

Comment: Especially `SaveChanges` as an *action* makes little sense. If you really want a long-lived UoW you'll have to implement it yourself instead of relying on DbContext. Maybe you could cache the DbContext instance *somewhere* but then you'd have to decide when to discard it. In any case this wouldn't work if you used two or more services for load balancing and availability

Comment: What are you trying to do? UoW doesn't apply across services. At this point you have  distributed transactions, sagas, orchestration. The complexity rises quickly, and that assumes that calls are stateless to begin with. That `SaveChanges` requires state and so is a very strong smell

Comment: I edited question for add UnitOfWork class.

Comment: So you're just aliasing DbContext. *Why* do you want to make `SaveChanges` a service action? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what I should? Is it wrong usage?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not just wrong, it makes no sense. A DbContext lives only for a single action. `SaveChanges` will get a different DbContext and thus UoW than any other request. Again, Unit of Work, at least in the way ORMs and your own code implement it, doesn't even apply across service calls

Comment: That `SaveChanges` means that *another service* takes part in the transaction and it's *the other service* that controls it. Is that what you want? Do you really have two services? Can't they communicate with a *single* POST? Why do they need to make multiple POSTs with a SaveChanges at the end?

Comment: Another thing that makes no sense. Your service is serving more than one client at a time. Whose changes will `SaveChanges` commit? As it is, it can only work if you accept only a single request at a time from a single client. Not even different requests from the same client, at least not if they belong to different UoWs. You'd need to use and keep track of a Session or TransactionID. That takes you away from UoW towards Sagas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months ; I solved this problem with another design pattern. I used to UnitOfWork structure at one Api(working as middleware one) and used chain of responsibility pattern.

For more information(18.05.2023);

If you want to act when savechanges stage you should use UnitOfWork pattern structure. But in this issue different by some reasons (I need different actions for different saving actions). The usable pattern was chain of responsibility because processes are follow each other. You should attribute for service classes that include save actions. This attribute reach UnitOfWork service or directly save method by Attribute param. But applying different methods for different actions is not proper for SOLID and when you request to this endpoint effect timeout errors.
So we have just one good case; you should build Generic service structure begin of the project.